# 1 image and two elements floating right next to it

Tags: css

I am trying to have 1 image and two elements floating right next to it (and the two elements on two separate lines). I tried working with display:inline-block so that each of the two elements comes on a separate line, but no luck. Also, the "brand" should be on top of the "model", thus first Mercedes and second W126. Is it possible to achieve this?

Fiddle here... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/f1xLk74L/3/)

HTML:

```
<div class="car"><img alt="" src=
       "http://placehold.it/50x50&text=CAR"></div>

    <div class="brand">
        Mercedes
    </div>

    <div class="model">
        W126
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.car img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin:0;
    display:block;
}

.brand {
    font-size:16px;
    color:#333333;
    font-family:'Droid Serif';
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-top:5px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-top:2px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.model {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#5A5A5A;
    font-family:'Droid Serif';
    font-style:normal;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    padding-left:10px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: inline-block does not do what it sounds like you think it does. Just get rid of display properties on those elements and float the image left. Adjust margins to fit. You don't need to float the 2 elements you want to be next to the image. They will automatically sit next to the floating element if there is room to fit. You can adjust your image's max-width to ensure there is always room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some floats instead:

```css
.car img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
}
.brand {
    font-size:16px;
    color:#333333;
    font-family:'Droid Serif';
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    padding-top:5px;
    margin-left:52px;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-top:2px;
}
.model {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#5A5A5A;
    font-family:'Droid Serif';
    font-style:normal;
    margin-left:2px;
    margin-right:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    padding-left:10px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=CAR">
</div>
<div class="brand">Mercedes</div>
<div class="model">W126</div>
```

Note that `.brand` has no float which allows the W126 to be pushed to the line below it, and the margin has been increased to space it properly.

Comment: Is the float on .model necessary?

Comment: @PaddyMack yes and no. Without it you'd need to adjust the margin like with .brand.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy if you change the HTML & CSS a bit:

```css
.car {
    display:inline-block;
}

.car img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    margin:0;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.car .makeAndModel {
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
    font-family:'Droid Serif';
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.brand {
    font-size:16px;
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
}

.model {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#5A5A5A;
    font-style:normal;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="car">
     <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/50x50&text=CAR" />
      <div class="makeAndModel">
            <div class="brand">
                Mercedes
            </div>   
   <div class="model">
                W126
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```